# Custom single.php files for different post formats

Tags: php, loop, post-formats, single

I have 3 custom post formats. One is for image, one for video, and, one for gallery besides the default post and they each have a view comments link on the bottom right corner at the end of the post.

Here is the code for that(it's in every formats php file):

```
<div class="post-comments">
<p class="postcoments"> <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> View responses </p>
</div> --></a> </div>
```

**Check it out here:**
http://benlevywebdesign.com/wordpress

On the single.php page I would like to get rid/remove the view comments link because you don't need to see it when you are viewing the comments already(its redundant).

I am new at wp and php so I need help

I have already read the wp codex that tells you to just make single.php and single-post_type.php and I didn't work. I am not sure what to do now.

Here is the current loop code in the single.php file: (it says in comment code "You are now viewing single.php" to see if goes to the single.php page as a test)

```
<!-- GRID 12 You are now viewing single.php -->
<div class="grid_12">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <!-- In case no posts were found -->
        <div class="post-cf">Hmmm? Can't. Find. Post.
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- CLOSE GRID 12 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I am not trying to detect when I am on a single page but I want to have custom single.php pages like the wp codex says I can by doing single-post_format.php so that I can be able to have control of what you see on the single page for the different post formats(getting rid of the view commenmts link)

The template hierarchy doesn't account for the post format taxonomy with respect to single blog post pages, which have a hierarchy of:

- `single-$posttype.php`
- `single.php`
- `index.php`

All posts that have the post format taxonomy have a `$posttype` of `post`. You could use `single-post.php`, but that really wouldn't help you in this case. You'll want to modify one/all of `content-image.php`, `content-video.php`, `content-gallery.php`, and `comments.php`.

Based on this comment:

> Would I have to take `<div class="post-comments"> <p class="postcoments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> View responses</p> </div> --></a> </div>` out of my `content.php` and other format type files and stick this in the `index.php` in between the loop code?

No, not really. I would recommend just wrapping that code in an `if ( is_single() )` conditional:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
    <div class="post-comments"> <p class="postcoments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> View responses</p> </div> --></a> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

That way, the "View Comments" code is not output on single blog post pages, but if the same `content-$format.php` is used to output Loop content on `index.php` (for the blog posts index, archive index pages, etc.), the "View Comments" code would still be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) to detect when you are on a single post page. Based on what you've provided I believe you'll want to use that in your `content-<post_format>.php` template.

Comment: I am not trying to detect when I am on a single page but I want to have custom single.php pages like the wp codex says I can by doing single-post_format.php so that I can be able to have control of what you see on the single page for the different post formats(getting rid of the view commenmts link)

Comment: Would I have to take 
`<div class="post-comments">
<p class="postcoments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
View responses</p> </div> --></a>
</div>` out of my content.php and other format type files and stick this in the index.php in between the loop code

Comment: Where are you seeing that there is a `single-post_format.php` template? As far as I know there are `single-post_type.php` templates, but post_formats are handled through `get_post_format()` etc. Your theme has this set up to be handled via `get_template_part('content', get_post_format());` which means that the template would be `content-post_format.php`. `content.php` would be the fall-back you can copy it to create new versions for each post format.

Comment: Maybe I don't mean `single-post_format.php`...What I basically want is to be able to hand code the php for the single page for a certain post format instead of using the loop code so I have more control over what It look like

Comment: You have just as much control in either case. But like I said, if the code you posted is in your `single.php` you should be able to create `content-image.php`, `content-video.php` and `content-gallery.php`. Assuming those are the names of your post formats.

Comment: I already have the post format phps working and that is not what I was asking but I solved it already